# Ext.net: how to set a width in percent instead pixel?

Tags: asp.net, extjs, ext.net

i would like to set GridPanel width, to 100%. My gridpanel is in a table.
I know i can only set gridpanel width in fixed pixel. 
So my question is: how to set width of panel, gridpanel etc. in percent in ext.net ? Is it possible ?
I don't want to "neste" it into a viewport ... 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i dont think you can specify values in percentages.

however if you set the value to 'auto' i believe it will automatically fill the space:

**Width and Height   Fixed values measured in pixels (or, device-independent units that are approximately 1/96 inch). You can set these properties to Auto so that child elements will automatically resize depending on the sizing of the parent panel.**

from microsoft

Comment: you are right ! i'm a stupid ;) i set the container with 80% instead 100% so i my grid didn't feel the screen... :)! Sorry for stupid question !

Answer (score 10):

To set the Width property declaratively to a unit type other than the default of Pixel, you must create a new unit type specific to the unit type you want. For example, to set a control's Width property to a percentage value of 100, you could do the following:

myWebControl.width = Unit.Percentage(100);